# Mypy thinks function which returns a Child instance actually returns Parent

Tags: python, mypy

Here is a simple reproduction:

```py
from typing import Union


class Parent:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("In Parent")


class A(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        print("In A")


class B(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        print("In B")


def factory(arg: str) -> Union[A, B]:
    mapper = {"A": A, "B": B}

    return mapper[arg]()
```

This seems to me like it ought to be typed correctly, but mypy reports the following error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Parent", expected "Union[A, B]")
```

It either produces an error with a bad argument, or one of the child classes specified in the Union. So why does mypy get Parent?

Is there some better way I can write this? This variant doesn't produce any error, but I prefer the former, especially if there were many cases:

```
def factory(arg: str) -> Union[A, B]:
    if arg == "A":
        return A()

    return B()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding typing to `mapper`, e.g.:`mapper: Dict[str, Union[Type[A],Type[B]]]`?

Comment: `mapper: Dict[str, Type[Union[A,B]]] = {"A": A, "B": B}` also seems to work: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=61738d1d943f3aab6b34eae74976413f

Comment: `mypy` infers the type `dict[str, def () -> tmp.Parent]` for `mapper`. Since `dict` is mutable, I assume it infers the more general type so that adding values to and removing values from `mapper` remain type-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will use your answer @UnholySheep, as it does the job well.